# Booktabs table lines not showing

Tags: tables, formatting, booktabs

I am using a conference template (see https://sice.jp/siceac/sice2022/01.html) to write my paper. When creating tables with the Booktabs package, all lines in the table are not showing. Plain tables work fine. Could anyone help me out here?
The packages I included:

```
\usepackage{multirow,makecell,booktabs}
```

The code where I create a table:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\label{table: data description} 
\center
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
        & Period                 & Length \\ \midrule
Data 1  &  a & 349\\ 
Data 2  &  b & 149\\
Data 3  &  c & 31 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And the created table in pdf file:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: use `\centering` not `\center`

Comment: @daleif Thanks, advice  accepted :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class and which font packages you employ. (Not all document classes, and not all fonts, play nice with the `booktabs` package.)

Comment: @Mico it is already mentioned in the first sentence. I can confirm that the `booktabs` rules does not work with it. Still no idea why. My guess is that `booktabs` assumes that some setting is always available in all classes and that this custom class does not provide it.

Comment: @Mico  It has something to do with the font set up. `\heavyrulewidth` is set in `booktabs` to be `0.08em`, but if you type it to log it is zero. It seems to be the setting of `\normalsize` which does not look like the normal, say `size10.clo`

Comment: Found a solution: issue `\normalsize` **before** loading `booktabs`. The normal classes issues `\normalsize` as soon as the font sizes have been set up. This class never executes it, thus any command that uses `em` units to set a length, will fails. You should probably send them an email to have them update their template.

Comment: @daleif I added `\normalsize` before loading `booktabs` and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @daleif - Some of us spend parts of our days behind a firewall that won't let us visit, e.g., the site mentioned by the OP. Hence my suggestion to be a bit more forthcoming...

Comment: @Mico sure, and i this case it was important, as it was the custom cls taht was the problem. My read of your comment was just that the OP had not given any information about their document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard classes, say, `article` uses `size10.clo` to define the font sizes. Here is the start of this file:

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize % <----  the important bit
```

note how it defines `\normalsize` and then executes it. This means that in the preamble the font relative units like `em` and `ex` are now known.

The `SICE22.cls` defines `\normalsize` but never executes it. Thus any length set in the preamble that uses `em` units, does not know the size of `em` and thus ends up being zero.

All rules from `booktabs` use `em` units to set their thickness.

Solution: Execute `\normalsize` in the preamble somewhere before loading `booktabs`.

*It is debatable whos fault it is*

Comment: Trying to understand here.  What if `\normalsize` were executed _after_ booktabs was loaded, but before any booktabs command was executed?  Would that work, or does booktabs convert em dimensions to pt at loading time?

Comment: @dedded no, if you look in `booktabs.sty` you'll see things like `\heavyrulewidth=.08em`, no tests as to whether `em` has been setup or anything. You can argue that this is a mistake from `booktabs`s side. I'm not sure, most classes execute `\normalsize` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no problem executing booktab rulings with pt, as in:

\toprule[1.5pt]

\midrule[1.25pt]

\bottomrule[1.5pt]

for example.

Comment: And you're use of the rules are the same as the OPs (hint they are not)

Comment: `your'!  I find it hard to discern what you are saying. These parameters work for me and have done for some considerable time.